# Does the ST bonus from Lifting ST apply to two-handed unbalanced weapons?

Tags: weapons, gurps-4e

A Great Axe has a minimal ST 12‡. This means that after an attack OR parry, it becomes unbalanced and requires a ready manoeuvre. In effect, it means it can only be used once every two turns. But if you have ST 18, it can be used every turn.

A character that has ST 15 can only use this weapon every 2 turns.

If this character has Lifting ST 3, would this issue be circumvented? The damage would still be assessed with ST 15, but load and balance would be of ST 18, correct?

Comment: What's the description of Lifting Strength vs. that of Striking Strength?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

Reverend Pee Kitty (Assistant Line Editor at the time of posting) checked this with the head Line Editor Kromm and [clarified here](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?p=1182696#post1182696) that this is how Lifting and Striking ST are used in figuring minimum ST levels:

> **When weapons have a minimum ST requirement, can I add Arm ST, Lifting ST, and/or Striking ST to my ST for this purpose?**
>
> Arm ST always helps if it applies to all arms necessary to use the weapon. [...]
>
> Lifting ST helps with *non-muscle-powered* weapons, like firearms. [...]
>
> Striking ST helps with *muscle-powered* weapons, from swords to thrown daggers to bows. The ST requirement for these weapons is primarily due to the need to use them dynamically -- you have to be able to swing, thrust, or pull with great force, which is what Striking ST is all about. (To some degree, Lifting ST could be argued to help, as it allows you to more easily support the weapon, but that's less of an issue than the need to attack with the weapon -- **thus, always use Striking ST**.)

(Final bolding mine.)

Therefore, to answer your question, **no, Lifting ST will *not* help you** meet the MinST requirements for the purposes of wielding the weapon easier (since all the weapons with the ‡ mark are muscle-powered ones), only ensure that you can *carry* it easier (being less encumbered).

Comment: Good answer, Vicky. +1 for sure.